# creating and editing temporary file in DropBoxAPI itself and then saving/uploading it

Tags: java, dropbox, dropbox-api

I have a piece of code where I check for a certain file (.xlsx) in a dropbox folder:

```
 ListFolderResult result = client.files().listFolder("some path");
        while (true) {
            for (Metadata metadata : result.getEntries()) {
                if(metadata.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name))
                {
                    System.out.println("Already exists file with name"+name);
                    return true;              //file exists.
                }
             }

            if (!result.getHasMore()) {
                break;
            }

            result = client.files().listFolderContinue(result.getCursor());
        }
        return false;   //file doesn't exists
```

This just searches for that file and return a boolean according to it.

Now, What I want is to **create a file for the same name in the dropbox itself** instead of creating it in my local system and then uploading it.
What I currently have is:

```
Boolean ifExists = checkInDrop(client,userName);   //client is dropbox config client and checkInDrop() is mentioned above.
        if(ifExists==false) 
        {
            try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(userName+".xlsx")) 
            {
                FileMetadata metadata = client.files().uploadBuilder("the same path mentioned above"+userName+".xlsx")
                    .uploadAndFinish(in);
            }
        }
```

Can you guys kindly suggest that if this is possible? If yes then how?

Thanks.

Comment: The [`uploadAndFinish`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v3.1.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/DbxUploadStyleBuilder.html#uploadAndFinish-java.io.InputStream-) method just takes an [`InputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html), but it doesn't have to be a `FileInputStream`. You could supply a different kind that doesn't come from a local file.

Comment: Also, you can use [`getMetadata`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v3.1.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/files/DbxUserFilesRequests.html#getMetadata-java.lang.String-) to check if a file exists at a specific path instead of searching through the whole file listing.